# Append data of Short, Int, Long Long... to char*

Tags: c++

I want to append the raw data of anything from `short`, `int`, `long long` to `byte` and `bool` to a `char*` or `void*`.

Here is what I came up with:

```
template <typename T>
static void memcopyToBytestring(T& target, size_t targetSize, char* previeous, size_t previousSize)
{
    if (target && targetSize > 0)
    {
        char newByteString[previousSize + targetSize];

        memcpy(newByteString, previeous, previousSize); //copy old
        memcpy(newByteString + previousSize, &target, targetSize); //add new

        previousSize += targetSize;
        previeous = new char[previousSize];

        memcpy(previeous, newByteString, previousSize);
    }
}
```

Something seems to be off and I don't even know what and how to correctly test this (look at the data of `target`)

Use case: I need to serialize data according to a predefined protocol to send the bytes out.

Question: how can I correctly append data to a char array?

Comment: erm... what!? and why?

Comment: Would you like to add a question to that?

Comment: Please don't use SO as your private blog or notepad. Use it only to *ask questions*.

Comment: edited post according to your suggestions. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `std::vector<char>` for this:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> stream;

template <typename T>
void AddToStream(T t)
{
    stream.insert(stream.end(), (char*)&t, ((char*)&t) + sizeof(t));
}
```

Then you can do:

```
AddToStream((int)0x12345678);
AddToStream(true);
AddToStream((byte)27);
```

Which results in this array:

```
[0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12, 0x01, 0x1B]
```

At the end, to get your byte array, use `stream.data()` and `stream.size()`

Comment: thank you very much. I got so hung up on my `*` I didn't even think about a `vector`. great answer :)

Comment: You're welcome. Just realized that instead of using `sizeof(t)`, you could also write: `stream.insert(stream.end(), (char*)&t, (char*)(&t + 1));`

Answer (score 0):

There is a [serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library in Boost. Perhaps you should have a look on it.